# 2.5: trying to uninstall a component but got error - how to manually uninstall a component and other questions

Tags: joomla-2.5, extensions, xml

[image]

I havn't touched this 2.5 site for a long time, now it needs to be upgraded to 3.4. In order for that I need to uninstall/upgrade extensions. When I try to uninstall one of them, I got this error as shown in the picture. There are several questions regarding this:

1)under `administrator` folder, no folder appears to correspond this component(AG_Google_Analytics2), where does joomla get the component list, a.k.a why is it shown in the extension manager?

2)I know when creating a component, we need to create a XML file listing all files the component will use, I guess the uninstaller also use this file to delete all the related files. It seems to me this XML file of this component in question has been missing, so is there anyway to manually uninstall it?

3)Is there any extension helping people deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall the component first, and then try to uninstall it again.